# Is there a way to update config files once build is done in jenkins

Tags: .net, jenkins, hudson

I am new to jenkins, I am working on .NET Project.

Right now we are using CC.NET with combination of NANT for our CI. We are  building one build and updating Config files using Xmlpoke as required by environment (qa,prod) .

I am able to compile my code in jenkins with MS build and Sln file combination , But stuck at config files update before deploy?

For example , I have to update below portion of webconfig file :

From :

```
<endpoint address="http://cmwebservice/CreditWebService.svc/Get/"
    behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
    contract="Credit.WebServiceHost.ICreditWebService">
</endpoint>
```

To

```
<endpoint address="http://somewebserver/CreditWebService.svc/"
    behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
    contract="Credit.WebServiceHost.ICreditWebService">
</endpoint>
```

Comment: Check your formatting, there is nothing to see for your example.

Comment: So you are asking on how to run XMLPoke in jenkins?

Comment: Nope. I am just asking i sther a way to find and replace a string in one config file once build is done.let me know if any plug in avialble  in hudson or jenkins

Comment: AFAIK there is no plugin that offers this specific kind of functionality. You can however use e.g. groovy scripting to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Make your config file into a template:

```
<endpoint address="ENDPOINT_ADDRESS"
```

Then you can use a pre-build or post-build "Execute shell" command to perform the replacement:

```
sed -i 's/replaceThis/withThis/g' $WORKSPACE/path.to.file
```